# Missing IIS Express option as web server in visual studio 2022 to run blazor web assembly project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-2022

For one of my .Net hosted blazor web assembly project, there is no option to run the project selecting IIS Express in my Visual Studio 2022. But I have WSL, http etc.

So in the debugger doesn't hit in any breakpoints in web assembly cs files.
Why am I missing the option??

Comment: Do you have other projects that have that option on the same machine?

Comment: Please try to change your launchSettings.json file, and tell me if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find `launchSettings.json` like below:

[image]

Then you can add `IIS Express` settings and save it, then you will find `IIS Express` option.

[image]

**My `launchSettings.json` file.**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:2590",
      "sslPort": 44334
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5131",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7193;http://localhost:5131",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have IIS Express settings in my launch options, but still get no option to run using IIS Express.